# index.html is not being displayed/loaded using app.js

Tags: javascript, express

I am trying to build a todo list with quite an old guide, the app.js works, but it doesn't send my html to display in local host, it just shows a blank page.

This is the code of app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(express.json())

app.get("/", function (req, res) {

    let today = new Date();

    if (today.getDay() === 0) {
        res.write("<h1>Yay It's the weekend</h1>");
    } else {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "todolist-v1\index.html");
    }

    res.send();

});



app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log(`App listening on port ${3000}`)
});
```

And this is the html.index file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>To Do List</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Shit doesnt work!!</h1>

    <p>What da fuck!?</p>


    <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

I expected localhost to display the index.html file, it only displays the app.js.

Comment: I would double check to make sure your path is correct in `res.sendFile(__dirname + "todolist-v1\index.html");` Also, try changing the '\' to '/' in the path like so `res.sendFile(__dirname + "todolist-v1/index.html");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I gave it a quick google search and looked into the `res.sendFile` Method. It seems that you have to give it an absolute path instead of a relative path.
Here's the resource I used: [res.sendFile(path [, options] [, fn])](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.sendFile)
However, you do have the option to use a relative path if you defined it in some options object.

Comment: Yeah, that is the first thing I tried and it still didn't work! I have asked ChatGPT for help and it was solved on the second try! What a time to be alive!

Comment: I'm glad your questions was answered ^^ after i read your own answer (btw you can say that this is the answer that helped you, so your questions isn't marked as open) i realized, that i totally missed the `__dirname`

Comment: Personally I don't care but ChatGPT answers don't have the highest reputation here on Stackoverflow. Also if you answer someone elses question, it's literally forbidden to just use ChatGPT and it can get punished...i don't know how it's handled when you answer your own questions by using ChatGPT and post that answer